# Container.removeall() freezes application

Tags: java, swing

So I am having a problem removing content from a content pane.

My code for this method is:

```
    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();

    try{
        pane.removeAll();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}

    pane.revalidate();
    pane.repaint();
```

I'm not even trying to add anything here, but this doesn't remove anything. The frame contains a JPanel with a JTextField and a JButton. The JButton has a listener that does a bunch of stuff before calling this method.

This problem is especially frustrating because I have used this exact method before in another app where it works just fine.

EDIT-
Ok, I made a simplified example, but it works exactly like it should. The only difference between my app and the example is the app is a client that receives instructions from a server program which is supposed to trigger the removal of the components.

Here is the example program

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RemoveButton{

    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        frame = new JFrame("Remove Components Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


        JTextField field = new JTextField(25);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;

        panel.add(field,constraints);


        JButton button = new JButton("Remove");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                                    try{
                                        updatePane();
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception ex){
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;

        panel.add(button,constraints);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static void updatePane(){

        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();

        pane.removeAll();

        pane.revalidate();
        pane.repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Trying to remove everything from the content pane makes me think what you should be doing is using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. `I have used this exact method before in another app where it works just fine.` Why are you using code like that? Whenever I see the removeAll() method I would suggest that you should probably be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Why are you catching an Exception? I'm not aware of the removeAll() method throwing an Exception. If it does throw an Exception then you should be displaying the exception message. Don't use an empty catch block.

Comment: As has been noted above, 1) CardLayout would work better, and 2) your limited posted code and information don't allow us to be able to understand or explain your program's misbehavior. The problem lies in code not shown, and so you should create and post your [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to allow us to understand your problem. Again, please read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to create this.

Comment: Note that a frozen Swing application usually implies that you've got long running code that is being called on the Swing event thread, and again, none of the code you've posted shows this,... so our recommendations for your [minimal runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) apply.

Comment: Thanks for posting your latest code above, but your GUI does not become frozen, and so your example program does not display the misbehavior that you're asking about, making it an invalid example. So, your problem is that you've yet to isolate the cause of your program's misbehavior, and this means that you're going to need to do more debugging to find it.

Comment: I could finally reproduce the problem but I am unable to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

> The only difference between my app and the example is the app is a client that receives instructions from a server program

That is a big difference. That is why we need proper demo code every time you post a question. We need all the information because until the problem is solved you don't know what infomration is or isn't relevant. And of course we don't have access to your server so in the future you need to create a demo that "simulates" what you are trying to do in order to demonstrate the problem.

Your code is probably blocking while waiting for the server to reply and therefore the GUI can't repaint itself.

You need to use a separate Thread whenever connecting with a server.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You should probably be using a `SwingWorder` to connect with the server.